# X Error of failed request: BadValue

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

I have tried to change my screen resolution but for some reason can't get it to change. I know my graphics card is capable because I had it changed before I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. I don't have an NVIDIA card, it's an Intel HD 520 (SKL GT2).
I am able to add the new resolution but I can't use it and after I reboot it's gone. I have added the lines to .xprofile in my home directory but that didn't have any effect either. Some of my programs have a the bottom of the screen cut off and I can't access some of the controls (namely Simplify 3D).
Here's the error message

```
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 1432x800_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Also, after upgrading my screen now flickers pretty often, I can get it to stop bt moving my mouse but it flickers about once or twice an hour.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to either issue. The screen flickering is actually getting worse.

Comment: Are there any fixes for this yet?